# How do I unlock Helena's knife in Leon and Helena's campaign?

Tags: resident-evil-6

A player joined my hosted game in Resident Evil 6 and played as Helena and had a knife for their weapon. In Leon and Helena's campaign, the knife is Leon's default weapon; for Helena it is Hydra.

Where did they get the knife for Helena? How can I unlock it myself? Is there some challenge to accomplish in the game to unlock Helena's knife?

Here is an example of Helena with a knife:

[image]